# How to best store and search address?

Tags: maps, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I'm building a service where people can basically find listings based on location. The service is offered in Germany and locations there seem to be extra tricky.

So how is the current setup?

To every listing I'm storing an address like that using nominatim data. The address data is based on zipCodes. So Im receiving zipCodes and out of this storing this address object:

```
address: {
suburb: "Neukölln",
city_district: "Neukölln",
city: "Berlin",
state: "Berlin",
postcode: "12053",
country: "Deutschland",
country_code: "de",
lat: "52.4775104",
lon: "13.4322809163976",
displayName: "Neukölln, Berlin, 12053, Deutschland"
},
```

The user in the frontend then uses autosuggest based on komoot api which gives me something in following format:

```
city: "Berlin"
country: "Deutschland"
name: "Berlin"
osm_id: 240109189
osm_key: "place"
osm_type: "N"
osm_value: "city"
postcode: "10117"
state: "Berlin"
```

As you can see I can search now with osm_value and name. So I would search city:Berlin.

Theoretically this works quite well. But for bigger cities like Berlin nominatim and komoot are giving very bad results. Often times with nomnatim city is missing even tough there is a city_district. (See this issue: https://github.com/openstreetmap/Nominatim/issues/1487)

My question would be: How could a proper data structure look like and do you have a better idea to build this? Paid services are fine - I just haven't found one proper (besides extremely expensive gmaps).

Requirements are:
Search for zipCode, city, city_district, village, town, county

Having roughly 300k geocodings per month